FileManager.default.trashItem Moves to subfolder/.Trash instead of ~/.Trash
When I call FileManager.default.trashItem(at: srcURL, resultingItemURL: &trashedPath)
the file ends up in /Users/jay/Library/CloudStorage/Dropbox/.Trash/file.png instead of /Users/jay/.Trash
Is this a bug? Is there a work around? I would like the file to go to the Recycle bin so that it can be restored, which is not the case with this current result.

But that doesn't happen for every file, does it?

Try trashing something using Finder. Does it also go to DropBox's trash? I've found this thread which suggested this is a macOS bug.

Nice find on that thread, no, the bug is fixed on my Mac. When I Cmd+Delete from Finder it goes to ~/.Trash and I verified that it is not in /Users/jay/Library/CloudStorage/Dropbox/.Trash/

Doing some more testing on this, my issue here does appear to be related to the bug that @Sweeper mentioned. Using fileManager.trashItem for files in CloudStorage moves them to a .Trash directory inside the source directory and not ~/.Trash. I am still looking for a fix

I rolled back your last edit. Please do not edit a solution into your question. If you have an answer that you think will help others, please post it as an answer below.
